# iPhone + file upload control

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, file, upload, controls

I have an application which uploads file from iPhone to web server.

Problem is that I want to give users a control like from which they can select the file / photo from the device and which is than uploaded on server.

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the UIImage content as a JPEG or PNG wrapped in NSData:

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
if( data ) {  // it's possible nil may be returned
    ;// do stuff here. 
    // see: link to other answer on SO below.
    // if you want to write to file, try:
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

[File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming)

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use an ImagePickerController that is the system component to allow a user to choose a photo.

Comment: I have tried to use the same, but I can't get the path of the Image I select. Please can you help me.