# Getting System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data error while upload image(data) via AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, .net, ios, web-services, afnetworking

I am following some tutorial for upload the image (data) via AFNetworking. I have done

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://184.154.0.24"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

//    NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//    [_params setObject:multiMData forKey:@"Bytes"];
//    [_params setObject:name forKey:@"UserId"];
//    [_params setObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"fileName"];
//    [_params setObject:@"png" forKey:@"contentType"];

//    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/IphoneVideoService/webservice.asmx/getStringData" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
{
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:multiMData name:@"stringReturn" fileName:@"stringReturn.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];


[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString); //Lets us know the result including failures
}];

//    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] ;
//    [queue addOperation:operation];

[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

After compiling i have got that error

```
2013-04-09 13:22:49.153 Softo Chat[582:19d03] Sent 323584 of 333526 bytes
2013-04-09 13:22:49.153 Softo Chat[582:19d03] Sent 327680 of 333526 bytes
2013-04-09 13:22:49.153 Softo Chat[582:19d03] Sent 331776 of 333526 bytes
2013-04-09 13:22:49.154 Softo Chat[582:19d03] Sent 333526 of 333526 bytes
2013-04-09 13:22:49.154 Softo Chat[582:1ad0b] System.InvalidOperationException: Request    format is invalid: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

and its server side programming asp.net

```
[WebMethod]
public string getStringData(string stringReturn)
{
    return stringReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hi Pravi jay i just google it and got one good Question related you. you just need to some change in to web.config.

```
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

please visit this:-

['System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data' error when posting image from iphone to .NET webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067742/system-invalidoperationexception-request-format-is-invalid-multipart-form-dat)