# asmx method always acting as HttpGet

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to implement HttpPost method on ASP.NET .asmx. I tried the follwing but it always acting as a httpGet method.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public void token()
{
   //enter code here
}
```

When I try a POST request on Postman, it return the following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: .    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

I have also added the following in the web.config

```
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpSoap"/>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
```

What other changes do I need to make to make it a HttpPost method?

Comment: How do you send the POST request? AJAX or code-behind?

Comment: @ShawnXiao actually, it's up to the client. Got to allow both ways

Comment: May this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253817/13378146) help you or not?

Comment: It looks like the issue with request. Plz share the request and the header settings in the postman and the calling URL format.