# How to send file along some POST variables with Objective-C iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, multipartform-data

I'd like to know {insert_title_here}?

I use this method, but with no success:

```
    //string data
    NSString *post = @"message=helloWorld";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    //file data
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageFile.png"];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPathToFile];

    //request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:@"http://www.example.com/"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //POST body
    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data]; 

    //append string data
    [postbody appendData:postData];

    //append file
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"iconFile\"; filename=\"ImageFile.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

    //set content length
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postbody length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    //send and receive
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: how can is done i also facing the same problem please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're attaching a file.

Check [File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming).

Comment: Yes, thanks, i found this post with ASIHTTPRequest mentioned just some 10 minutes ago ;]

Comment: how can is done i also facing the same problem please let me know –

Comment: This answer seems worded by Clippy, can't help but imagine the thing jumping at the bottom of my screen. Made my day ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this.. **very easy to understand & implementation**...

```
- (void)simpleJsonParsingPostMetod
{

#warning set webservice url and parse POST method in JSON
    //-- Temp Initialized variables
    NSString *first_name;
    NSString *image_name;
    NSData *imageData;

    //-- Convert string into URL
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"demo.com/your_server_db_name/service/link"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //-- Append data into posr url using following method
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


    //-- For Sending text

        //-- "firstname" is keyword form service
        //-- "first_name" is the text which we have to send
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"firstname"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",first_name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //-- For sending image into service if needed (send image as imagedata)

        //-- "image_name" is file name of the image (we can set custom name)
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",image_name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //-- Sending data into server through URL
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    //-- Getting response form server
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    //-- JSON Parsing with response data
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Result = %@",result);
}
```

You can **download sample code** directly here https://github.com/Tech-Dev-Mobile/Json-Sample