# iPhone SDK : How to save a image as a file and POST it back to PHP server?

Tags: iphone, image, file-upload, sdk

I'm look for a solution to upload an image file to PHP server

I find some tutorial to get a photo from [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmZjsTW0G94)

and you can get source code [here](http://davidporterapps.com/SourceCode/iPhoto.zip)

How can I use an IBAction to send the photo to a URL server

for example I give it a URL:http://someaddress/photo_upd.php

or more specific, **HOW TO CONVERT IMAGE I GET FROM CAMERA -> NSDATA ???**

I think [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming) will be help,but I don't know how to use it ...

this is my program main function,I use a camera to take a photo

and I press a button It will send the image and the GPS location

now I only can send GPS location,but don't know how to upload the image

Hope someone know the solution !

Great thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSData* YourData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0); this will give you the data representation of your image
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try it.But how can I know I pass the image to NSData ?

Comment: i have posted you the way to convert an image into NSData

Comment: OK...I think it's really got data inside,thanks a lot .I use if (photoData == nil) {
  NSLog(@"The photo is nothing !!!");
 }
 else {
  NSLog(@"Photo inside !!!!");
 } to check data exist or not.