# Files Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming)

How can i upload images and text to HTTP server in iphone programming...and which API used for it........

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most popular 3rd party library in all of iOS is ...

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

basically every single iPhone app uses it.  the instructions are trivial and are right there on the page - enjoy

Do not forget to make a donation to the guy, even a small one -- if he stops supporting it the entire iPhone industry will collapse!

Answer (score 0):

This is already been discussed here

[File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming)