# Camera is not working in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera

I have implemented the following and camera is opened but app is crashed and sometime when open and take the pictures then app is crasshed and log only show "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates Received memory warning."

The same functionality I have used for take the image from gallery and its working.

```
 -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:      (NSInteger)buttonIndex{
  if (buttonIndex==0) {
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                              message:@"Device has no Camera!"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }else{

        [self performSelector:@selector(loadCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

    }    
}
}


-(void)loadCamera{

picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker1.delegate = self;
picker1.allowsEditing=YES;
picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: Please refer this : I think its helpfull [Open Camera in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812945/opening-camera-in-iphone-app-programatically)

Comment: CJ Now did you get the solution?

Comment: Did you try all below answer?If not,tell me.

Comment: I used the below but app still crash and also use its delegates - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

Comment: I call this camera function under the actionsheet action. Is that any issue ?

Comment: Used this code without actionsheet the problem is still same also after  adding picker1.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

Comment: Now the same camera code is working but sometime when connected with Xcode it crashed with same error.

Comment: I noticed that the camera is crashed in iPad only

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by following code:

```
-(void)loadCamera{
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  
            {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker1.delegate = self;
            picker1.allowsEditing=YES;
            picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion: nil];

         });
       }
   }
```

This code worked for me with iOS 9.2 and xCode 7.2

Comment: Also in ios 12.1 this was a bug reported by appstore to my application. I added dispatch_async and it started working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)takeAPhoto:(VSButton *)sender {


    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }else {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

}
```

Comment: presentModalViewController was deprecated in iOS 6. suggested to use presentViewController@Muhammad Raheel Mateen

Comment: I will paste the method , this is running in my project too.

Comment: Its show error and app is crashed > Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(loadCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
-(void)loadCamera

{
if ([UIIagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)

{

picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker1.delegate = self;
picker1.allowsEditing=YES;
picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

}
```

Comment: I used the above but app still crash and also use its delegates - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {