# Iphone Upload File source code objective c

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, forms, upload

what is equivalent iphone (objective c) code to

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="page2.php">
<input type="file" name="File">
<input type="submit" name="uploadbtn">
</form>
```

i want to upload file from iphone to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to POST from your device to your server.

You can use the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) library to do this or use the built in NSURLConnection class.

Look specifically at the "Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest" section in the ASIHTTPRequest documentation.

If you can't use a third party library you will have to use NSURLConnection. You can find examples of how to use NSURLConnection here: [File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming)

Comment: i am not allowed to use external library