# upload image file to webservice in iphone?

Tags: iphone, web-services, url, uiimage

i'm try to upload the image to webservice along with "uniqueIdentifier","to phonenumber","from phonenumber","key"

this is the my url

> http://api.appname.com/index.php/api/bookmark/?uniqueIdentifier=74r587f87das48wq78rtqwer87r8weq&to=15128569514&from=15127052402&image=&key=506df2058254de29f73a64a084766e50

i got response as upload fail.....

Can you please give me the solution

Comment: You could do this by converting the image data to a base 64 string and send that as the parameter. On the webservice you can then convert the base64 string to byte code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ASHTTPRequest and ASIFormDataRequest. Refer this [Link1](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming).

Thanks!