# Updating data in web service

Tags: iphone

I am extracting data from web service(xml file) using NSXmlParser.How can I write to that xml file.I want to actually perform update ,insert and delete operations on that web service

Comment: you want to preform these operations to use it your self or you want to save it back to the server?

Comment: I want to save it back to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This post is written after reading your comment on the Question.*

You need to understand how to upload data from iPhone to server, for that please see this link:

[File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming)

mainly you will need to use:

```
NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest
```

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: I want to synchronize data using web service. I got the data and works fine in tableview. But my problem is that, when I put addtocart value '1' and submit, it also update value in server or website using webservice. I am getting data it works fine. But not updated on web server when i click on addtocart. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ResponseXML and modify the data inside.

You will send this xml through a webservice that saves it online (probably another webservice seen that the one you are using seems to only send and not receive data)

Comment: I want to post data to webserver and update user data(Addtocart) using  web service. I got all data using webservice but not update on server when i click on add to cart.any idea?