# upload image to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to upload an
`UIImage`
to a server.

the problem i dont know how to add it to my post to the server.
until now i sent post with thia:

```
NSString *reqURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url"];
    reqURL = [reqURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqURL]];
    NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
```

there is any different way to do for image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

```
-(void)uploadImage{
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Upload a file on disk
    [request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
forKey:@"photo"];

   // Upload an NSData instance
  [request setData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myUIImage) withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];

  [request setDelegate:self];
  [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
  [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];

  [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming/938025#938025) points to [this wrapper framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) that should make it easy to do what you want without dealing with HTTP header strings and so on.

Basically, you'll turn your `UIImage` into an `NSData` object using a function like `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` and then upload it over HTTP.