# Image is not uploading into webservice

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to upload an image into webservice, but when i upload it only name of the image is saving, but not image.

Please find the code and images for your reference.

```
    - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSData *image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.1);

    NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=thefile&&filename=recording"];
    [urlString appendFormat:@"%@", image];
    NSData *postData = [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                               allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSString *baseurl = @"http://192.168.2.34/Service1.svc/upload/filename.png";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseurl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];

    NSLog(@"Started!");

}
```

after uploading image and name of the image appears as below:

[image]

But when i open the image is show nil.

[image]

i am not sure what is going wrong..kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are wrong:

```
NSData *image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.1);
NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=thefile&&filename=recording"];
[urlString appendFormat:@"%@", image];
NSData *postData = [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
...
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Replace with:

```
NSData *image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.1);
...
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:image];
```

Also you should probably change 0.1 to 0.8 or something, or else the quality will be terrible.

You will also need to make sure the server is correctly reading the data. This depends what you are using server side... in PHP this is how you do it:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents($data, 'filename.jpg');
```

Comment: Video is the same, just get an NSData object for the video file, and provide it to setHTTPBody. Maybe also check if the user is on wifi.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in:

```
[urlString appendFormat:@"%@", image];
```

You are linking the description of the NSData object in the post data and this is an error.
To upload a binary file you need to serialize your data or use a multipart/form-data POST request.

These are the 2 solutions:

1) Convert image NSData in Base64 with this category (tested)

https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64

and then do

```
[urlString appendFormat:@"&image=%@", [image base64EncodedString]];
```

You need to convert on the server the base64 data back using (in PHP)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

2) Implement 
[File Upload to HTTP server in iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming)

I hope this helps.