# Not able to upload image from iOS App to Asp.net MVC

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to upload an image from iOS App to my asp.net mvc based site. I am writing this code from local side but for some reason HttpPostedFileBase is null... I can't find anything wrong, any tips why?

iOS side:

```
-(void)Upload
{
    NSLog(@"Upload stuff");

    NSString *urlString = @"http://.... ";

    // set up the form keys and values (revise using 1 NSDictionary at some point - neater than 2 arrays)
    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"auth",@"text",@"location",nil];
    NSArray *vals = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"au",@"txt",@"loc",nil];

    // set up the request object
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //Add content-type to Header. Need to use a string boundary for data uploading.
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //create the post body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    //add (key,value) pairs (no idea why all the \r's and \n's are necessary ... but everyone seems to have them)
    for (int i=0; i<[keys count]; i++) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",[keys objectAtIndex:i]] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[vals objectAtIndex:i]] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    }
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.btnCover.imageView.image, 1.0);


    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    // set the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(returnString);


    NSLog(@"Upload done");

}
```

Asp.net MVC Controller Action Side:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string PostFile(HttpPostedFileBase name)
    {

        var track = new Tracking();//this is my custom tracking class

        track.LogVisit(".", "start");
        track.LogVisit(".", (name == null).ToString() );
        track.LogVisit(".", name.ContentType);
        track.LogVisit(".", name.FileName);
        track.LogVisit(".", name.InputStream.Length.ToString());
        track.LogVisit(".", name.ContentLength.ToString());
        track.LogVisit(".", "end");

        return "k";
    }
```

Comment: did you found solution for this? i m also facing same issue...

Comment: yes, I solved it using ASIHTTPRequest to upload image to server. I don't have to code here, but it is very simple, just google it

Comment: can you post the iOS and asp code at parkarfahim22@yahoo.co.in Please send me... I am getting error as `Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449.
`

Comment: but ASIHTTPRequest is supported by ios5 onwards... right?

Comment: see comment here http://stackoverflow.com/a/938025/1066828