# iOS : How to send both a PDF file and a value in a HTTP request?

Tags: ios, asp.net, pdf, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I need to send a PDF file with a value (basically a `String`) to an .ASP endpoint.

I know how to fetch a file with `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and how to transform it as a `Data` object. I've also red [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming) as a start to send a file to an endpoint, but I don't know how to send another value alongside with the file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The endpoint would normally have a way for you to do this and specify it.  For example, with a querystring parameter, like URL?extrastring=s

Comment: @LouFranco Thanks for your answer. So if I get it right, the whole request should be a `POST` one like `URL?extrastring=s&data=[bytearray]`, is it correct?

Comment: A post would have the byte array in the body.

Comment: That information should be provided by your endpoint developer.  But, usually you would not send a PDF that way -- you'd do it like you do a file upload. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work

Comment: Read Lou Franco's link to see how to send multipart forms.  You can encode multiple things in the POST body, which use separator strings.  Also, you could just send the PDF, and send the string as part of the URL, or also as an HTTP header.  But you still have to ask the question, how does my .ASP endpoint expect to see this data?